# Does git-merge add files from the "to-be-merged" branch to head or not

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

So me and my team are working on a project under the agile development process. Every iteration there are several branches off of the `test` branch. Each branch acts as a task for the iteration. When the iteration is finished, all task branches are merged into the `test` branch and the `test` branch is merged into `master`.

The problem I am running into is merging `test` into `master`. In this specific case, `master` is quite behind and `test` has many files that aren't even included in `master`. So when I go to compare `test` and `master`, through a pull request, it acts like all the new files in `test` won't be added to `master`.

Is this how git-merge works? It only updates the changed files in `master` and doesn't care about added files?

So is my only option to do a git-rebase? If so, how does that work?

EDIT: I may have found the source of my issue. What if some task branches were branched off of `master` at the beginning of the iteration, then merged into `test` at the end. Would that cause some issues when merging `test` into `master`? Whenever I'm viewing my `test` branch on Github, it says, "This branch is 7 commits ahead, 5 commits behind master".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In light of your edit, let's break this into two parts.

*First, your direct questions about how different git operations should behave:*

> Is this how git-merge works? It only updates the changed files in master and doesn't care about added files?

No; any change on the remote branch - including addition of a new file - should be incorporated by the merge.  If this isn't happening, something else is going on.

> So is my only option to do a git-rebase?

With a couple exceptions based on edge cases, you should expect the resulting content (`TREE`) to be the same for a rebase as for a merge.  Whatever it is that's keeping your merge from performing as expected would likely *also* cause a rebase to behave in an unexpected way.

The choice to rebase or to merge is (in theory) only about how history is preserved.

*Second: Ok... so what's really going on here?*

It's hard to say *exactly* what's happening, because it's hard to have enough information about the current state of the repo.  But I can draw up a few scenarios and talk a bit about how merge works, and maybe that will give you enough to go on that you can trouble-shoot it...

Say you initiate a merge like this:

```
git checkout branchA
git merge branchB
```

Now `git` is going to identify three commits:

- *ours* - the commit that's checked out (i.e. what `branchA` points to)
- *theirs* - the commit whose history is being merged in (i.e. what branchB` points to)
- *base* - a "merge base" between *ours* and *theirs*.  Typically this can be summed up as "the most recent common ancestor of *ours* and *theirs*"

So if you have

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- O <--(branchA)
      \
       E -- F -- T <--(branchB)
```

then `O` will be *ours*, `T` will be *theirs*, and `B` will be *base*.

Next git will calculate a patch (diff, roughly) between `B` and `T` - which we can call "their changes" - and also a patch between `B` and `O` - which we can call "our changes".

If commit `E` adds a previously-nonexistent file `foo.txt`, then there will be no change for that file in our changes (because it didn't exist in either `B` or `O`), but `foo.txt` will be a new file in their changes (because it didn't exist in `B` but it did exist in `T`).

Now git wants to create a combined patch that contains our changes and their changes.  This is where conflicts can turn up, if our changes and their changes both attempt to modify the same hunk of code.  But in our "new file" scenario, there wouldn't be a conflict since our changes say nothing about `foo.txt`.  The combined patch should include "new file `foo.txt`" with the file's content as it appears at `T`.

So most of the time, if `merge` is behaving in a confusing way, you can start to understand it by knowing what is being used as the merge base.

```
git merge-base branchA branchB
```

will print out a commit ID.  The question is, does the commit contain `foo.txt`?  If it does, then you're not going to get the behavior you expect; and then the problem is reduced to "figure out why the calculated merge base contains `foo.txt`.

Now in the above example, this command would return the ID for `B`, which does not contain `foo.txt`.  So why might it be different in your case?

In your edit, you describe that some branches were created from master and merged to test.  This is not necessarily a problem.  Say we have

```
A -- B <--(master)
```

and you say

```
git checkout master
git branch test
```

then some work occurs on `test`.

```
A -- B <--(master)
      \
       C -- D <--(test)
```

and now someone creates a task branch, but they create it from `master`.

```
A -- B <--(master)
     |\
     | E -- F <--(task1)
      \
       C -- D <--(test)
```

Then they merge `task` into `test`

```
A -- B <--(master)
     |\
     | E ----- F <--(task1)
      \         \
       C -- D -- T <--(test)
```

Some other work goes on affecting `master`

```
A -- B -- G -- H -- O <--(master)
     |\
     | E ----- F <--(task1)
      \         \
       C -- D -- T <--(test)
```

Now in this case, the fact that `task1` was created "from `master`" doesn't matter.  In fact, nothing currently stored in `git` even *reflects* the fact that it was created from `master`; it could just as well have been created from `test` before commit `C`.

Meaning the merge would still work fine.

But here's a different scenario...  What if the person who created `task1` from `master` actually committed changes to `master` before realizing they needed to branch?  So in this case we start again from

```
A -- B <--(master)
      \
       C -- D <--(test)
```

and a developer starts coding `task1` on `master`.  They commit, and you ahve

```
A -- B -- E <--(master)
      \
       C -- D <--(test)
```

Then someone says "hey, dude, you can't just work directly on `master`", and so we try to fix things.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b task1
# work continues on the task1 branch
git commit
```

And some other work happens on `master`, so now you have

```
A -- B -- E -- G <--(master)
      \    \
       \    F <--(task1)
        \
         C -- D <--(test)
```

which looks pretty good, but someone says "hey, we can't have the changes form `E` on `master` until `test` gets merged back; and we can't afford the problems that a history rewrite would cause.  So..."

```
git checkout master
git revert HEAD^
```

and we have

```
A -- B -- E -- G -- ~E <--(master)
      \    \
       \    F <--(task1)
        \
         C -- D <--(test)
```

Everything on each branch looks right, so work continues

```
A -- B ------- E -- G -- ~E -- H -- O <--(master)
      \         \
       \         F <--(task1)
        \         \
         C -- D -- T <--(test)
```

But now when you try to merge `test` into `master`, something terrible happens:  `git` figures that the merge base is `E`, because of the common ancestors between `master` and `test`, `E` is the one that can reach all of the others / cannot be reached by any of the others.

So with `E` as the merge base, *their changes* don't affect `foo.txt` (because it was already created in `E`), whereas *our changes* deleted `foo.txt` (in `~E`).  So the merge result has no `foo.txt`, and this is not a change from the branch - it's a change already in `master`'s history - so the PR report says nothing about it.

Do I know this is exactly what happened?  No.  Would I bet it was something pretty much like this?  Yes.  Can I spell out a procedure to fix it?  Not really, because the exact steps are likely to be involved and to depend on *exactly* what happened.

For now I'd start by trying to confirm if the problem is fundamentally what I've suggested.

Comment: First of all, thanks a bunch for taking the time to help me, I appreciate it. So to start, after doing `git merge-base master test`, I checked, and the commit did include the missing files. So I am sure that nobody made changes to `master` before creating a new branch, but I am pretty sure that I know what might be causing this issue. A week or so ago, somebody accidentally merged a task branch into `master`, instead of `test`. They reverted the merge, but the commit history is still there in master. Do you think that this could be causing the issue?

Comment: I just saw that I missed this comment months ago.  I'm sure Jacob has moved past this issue, but for posterity: Yes, that would absolutely cause the same problem.  The git docs talk about this almost as though it were something you might do on purpose - they say that reverting a merge signals to git that you will *never* want what's on the reverted side of the merge.  You can search for questions about reverted merges for more info

Comment: Yep, if my memory serves me right, this was the issue. And your post helped me to better understand git merge's in general, and come to the realization that the reverted merge was what caused the issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`git merge` incorporate all changes from `test` to `master`, i.e. the changed, added and removed files in `test` will be changed, added or removed in `master`.

Your steps to do would be:

```
git checkout master
git merge test 
// if required: fix merge conflicts, shouldn't be required if `test` was in `sync` with master at the start of your sprint
git commit // if fixing merge conflicts were necessary
git push
```

In the ideal world, when `master`and `test`are in sync at the beginning of the sprint and everything can merged back the two branches will be again in sync at the end of your sprint. Your workflow resemble [gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) - only you call your branch `test`instead of `develop`.

My recomendation: avoid rebase if possible when multiple persons are working on the repo (branch). It is history rewritting with according risk.

Also the source code management tools like github, TFS or VSTS are merging and not rebasing.

Please see also the documentation https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: Yea, you say it incorporates all the changes, but I'm still seeing lots of missing files during the pull request. Check out the edit I made to my original post.

Comment: No, it should no any harm if you branch several times from `master` and merge them all to one common `test` branch.
What can lead to your issue if you delete files from one branch `A`, modify it in branch `B`. Now first merge`A` in `test`- the file will be deleted - and now `B`into `test`. It will see that the file with a common ancestor has been deleted and might assume that the file should be kept out of the merge result.

Comment: Well that may have occurred, I'm not sure. But taking all this into account, due to the fact that I need **all** the changes from `test` merged into `master`, is git-rebase my only option?